# How to create a random decimal between 0 and 1 vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I need a random decimal between 0 and 1 in VB.NET

```
Dim value As Decimal = CInt(Int((1 * Rnd()) + 0))
```

I'm trying this but it's just saving as `0`. It's definitely something I'm doing wrong but I'm not sure yet.

It should be between `0` and `1`, but it's just returning `0`.

Comment: The integer value of any random number between 0 and 1 is 0.

Comment: Exactly.  You can't store a real number in an `Integer` variable.  You need to use a `Single`, `Double`, or `Decimal` variable to hold the value.

Comment: it is a decimal

Comment: Don't use `CInt`

Comment: It should be `Decimal` but if you use `Int` and `CInt` then you're creating an `Integer`.

Comment: Don't use `Randomize` and `Rnd` in VB.NET anyway.  Create an instance of the `Random` class and use that.  In this case, call its `NextDouble` method and than pass the result to `Convert.ToDecimal` or, if you prefer, `CDec`.

Comment: Also, if you're using .NET, I would strongly recommend that you use the .NET Framework's `Random` class, which is more powerful and easier to use, rather than using the old `Rnd` function which is mainly just there for backwards compatibility with pre-.NET code.

Answer (score 1):

CInt will convert your Decimal value to an Integer value. Besides, Rnd is so 15 years ago, use Random.NextDouble instead:

```
Dim r As New Random() 'Should be declared at the topmost level
Dim value As Double = r.NextDouble()
```

Fiddle: [Live Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/iI4hDI)

Answer (score 0):

The function `Rnd` already returns a decimal number between 0 and 1. ([Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.vbmath.rnd?view=netframework-4.7.1))

Just use:

```
Dim Value as Decimal = Rnd()
```

Comment: `Rnd` returns a `Single` so that code relies on `Option Strict Off`. Ideally, you should be using `CDec` or `Convert.ToDecimal` to make an explicit conversion that will work with `Option Strict On`.

Answer (score 0):

RND Class already generates a decimal

```
Dim RandomOperator as new Rnd()
Dim Value as double = RandomOperator()
```